# DatePicker in my EditText

Tags: android, datepicker

In the Login page, the user must enter his birth day.
I want to creat un EditText (Birth Day), and the DatePicker show up.

I do like this :

```
public class Main extends Activity {

    EditText inputBirthDay;
    DatePicker dpResult;

    TextView tvDisplayDate;
    int year;
    int month;
    int day;

    static final int DATE_DIALOG_ID = 999;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.register_activity);     

        inputBirthDay = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.registerBirthDay);  
            inputBirthDay.setFocusableInTouchMode(false);       
        addListenerOnButton();      
    }   

    public void addListenerOnButton() {
        inputBirthDay.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
                year = c.get(Calendar.YEAR);
                month = c.get(Calendar.MONTH);
                day = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
                showDialog(DATE_DIALOG_ID);
                                    inputBirthDay.requestFocus();   
            }
        });     
    }

    private DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener datePickerListener = new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {

        // when dialog box is closed, below method will be called.
        public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int selectedYear,
            int selectedMonth, int selectedDay) {
        year = selectedYear;
        month = selectedMonth;
        day = selectedDay;

     inputBirthDay.setText(new StringBuilder().append(day)
                .append("-").append(month + 1).append("-                 ").append(year)
                .append(" "));
        }
    };

    @Override
    protected Dialog onCreateDialog(int id) {
        switch (id) {
        case DATE_DIALOG_ID:
            return new DatePickerDialog(this, datePickerListener, year, month,
                day);
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

But I have a problem :

1/ When I clik on the EditText, the keyboard show up in the first time, then wehen I clik again, the DatePicker show up. How can I hide the keyboard ?

Thank you for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For no.1 may be this will be enough:

```
inputBirthDay.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_NULL);
```

For no.2 i think this:

```
inputBirthDay.setText(String.valueOf(year)+String.valueOf(month)+String.valueOf(day));
```

put it in 'onDateSet' function

Comment: For the first, when I clik on the first time, nothing happen.. The DatePicker show up when I clik 2 times on EditText

Comment: @Humoule use this android:focusable="false"

Comment: @Humoule I tried your code with this edition  and it works fine. make sure you put android:focusable="false" on your layout file or inputBirthDay.setFocusable(false); in your code

Comment: Problem resolved. I edited my question.
Hope this help another one :)
Thank you very much Saif !